# Calling grep with mulitple variables pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, escaping, tcl

how can I use multiple patterns with grep in tcl?

```
set finish [exec bash -c "cat /home/new.txt |grep \"$day\|$yesterday\" > /home/new_tmp.txt"]
```

it works in the `bash` console

```
day=26.01.2020
yesterday=26.01.2020
cat /home/new.txt |grep "$day\|$yesterday"
```

but with Tcl script, the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first trial would be:

```
set from /home/new.txt
set to /home/new_tmp.txt

set day 26.01.2020
set yesterday 26.01.2020
# Did you mean these two to be the same?

catch {exec grep "$day|$yesterday" <$from >$to}
# Because grep returns non-zero if it doesn't find anything, which exec converts to an error
```

You don't actually need an external `cat` very often, either in Tcl or in Bash.

Be aware that `grep` matches `.` with *any* character.

Answer (score 1):

A general `grep`  tip: Since you're searching for multiple fixed strings, not really regular expressions, you can tell `grep` that to get a more efficient approach (And fix the issue of `.` being treated as a metacharacter and not an exact match):

```sh
grep -F -e "$day" -e "$yesterday" /home/new.txt > /home/new_tmp.txt
```

Or just do it all in pure tcl instead of getting a shell involved?

```
set infile [open /home/new.txt r]
set outfile [open /home/new_tmp.txt w]
while {[gets $infile line] >= 0} {
    if {[string first $day $line] >= 0 || [string first $yesterday $line] >= 0} {
        puts $outfile $line
    }
}
close $infile
close $outfile
```